# A counter strike map with only grenades?

Tags: counter-strike

I am looking for a custom CS map where you can't buy any weapons, and can fight with only grenades you pick off the ground. Can anybody link to such a map?

Comment: Reason for downvote??

Comment: This brings back fond memories of he_glassfloor

Comment: the dodgeball map mod is similar to this but instead of grenades exploding, the goal is to just hit the opposing team with the grenade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look here:

- http://maps.cs-bg.info/maps/cs/he/
  (CS 1.6)
- http://www.gamebanana.com/maps/search?search=grenade
  (CS 1.6 + CSS)

Or just search "he_" Maps with google or something.

Comment: Or simply filter games in your steam list by he_

Answer (score 2):

**he_pool_night** and just about any map that starts with **he_**.

Answer (score 0):

The map `he_tennis2` only has grenades on the ground and there's a mirror between Ts and CTs.